# pip or setuptools not working in python 3

Tags: python

I am using python 3 with Archlinux. Whenever I want to use pip to install packages, most packages fail to install and report the same problem:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.check_if_exists()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 928, check_if_exists
    self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(self.req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 461, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 341, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 740, in resolve
    env = Environment(self.entries)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 927, in __init__
    self.scan(search_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 957, in scan
    self.add(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 977, in add
    dists.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('hashcmp'), reverse=True)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < str()
```

Is it a bug of pip or setuptools?

Comment: That is caused by changes between Python 2.x and 3.x - looks like you have the wrong `pip` for your Python. Have you tried `pip3`? Alternatively, what are you trying to install, and does it support 3.x?

Comment: Default python on Archlinux is python 3, so I don't need pip3. But pip2(python2 on Archlinux) works fine.